# Selectors with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying something with royal slide. I want to change the ID according the image change.
I tried some stuff like using translateX values but it's really difficult to me, because I don't have much experience with jQuery/JavaScript. So I thought of another idea when I saw this:

```
<div class="rsNav rsBullets">
   <div class="rsNavItem rsBullet rsNavSelected"><span></span></div>
   <div class="rsNavItem rsBullet"><span></span></div>
   <div class="rsNavItem rsBullet"><span></span></div>
</div>
```

I thought that the best option was to use the `:nth-child` selector like this:

```
function colorfondo(){
if($('.RsNav:nth-child(1)').hasClass("RsNavselected")) {
   console.log('works!');
}
```

but it didn't work.

EDIT
Maybe i didnt explain it very well. I just want something like this:

```
if (the first child has the rsNavSelected) { do something.}
elseif the second child has the rsNavSelected) { do something.} elseif the third child has the rsNavSelected { do something.}
```

RE-EDIT
I made it work,thats my function
function colorfondo(){

```
if($('.rsNav div:first-child').hasClass("rsNavSelected")) {
console.log('rojo!');
} 
else if($('.rsNav div:nth-child(2)').hasClass("rsNavSelected")) {
console.log('azul!');
} 
else if($('.rsNav div:nth-child(3)').hasClass("rsNavSelected")) {
console.log('gris!');
} 
}
```

Now i need that this function doesnt stop and stay always working,any suggestions?

Comment: You have a function which needs to be called after an event. Now my question is what is that event or when this function is going to be executed?

Comment: first of all, what did not worked ?
second: there is no class ".RsNav" in your html.

Comment: What empiric is cryptically saying is that class names are case sensitive.  RsNav and rsNav are NOT the same thing.

Answer (score 4):

`RsNavselected` is not equal to `rsNavselected` and `RsNav` is not `rsNav`.

**HTML attributes values are case-sensitive, but HTML tag names and attributes not**.

Use :

```
if($('.rsNav:nth-child(1)').hasClass("rsNavSelected")) {
   console.log('works!');
}
```

Also, if you want to get `first-child` use `.children()` and `.first()` methods:

```
if($('.rsNav').children().first().hasClass("rsNavSelected")) {
   console.log('works!');
}
```

Comment: if($('.rsNav').children().hasClass("rsNavSelected")) { console.log('works!'); } This works in the console,but i need to know what element is it ( the 1st,the 2nd or the 3rd). Thank you!

Comment: Maybe i didnt explain it very well.
I just want something like this:          
    if the first child has the rsNavSelected
     {    do something.}
    elseif the second child has the rsNavSelected
     {    do something.}
    elseif the third child has the rsNavSelected
      {   do something.}

Comment: Try this http://jsfiddle.net/wwbkL68d/, it get `index` of selected `child` and by `switch` operator call `console.log`

Comment: Thanks! As i wrote on the top,i finally make it works,but this option looks cleaner than the other one,but my question is how can  i make function to doesnt stop and stay always working?any suggestions?

Comment: Better to close(accept right, probably my, answer) this question and ask another one.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use like :

```
if($('.rsBullets').find(".rsNavselected").length > 0) {
    console.log('works!');
}
```

Comment: why length?I dont understand.

Comment: Because if you find element **div.rsNavSelected** in **div.rsBullets** its length is greater than 0 otherwise should be 0.